# Android API 30 Cannot Detect multi-touch on the Android Emulator

Tags: android

I have a view and I want to implement detection of multi-touch gestures, so I override the onTouch() event and there I implement the logic. I have tested it and it work on actual device with Android API 28, and it works on Android Emulator up to API 29. As seen on the image below, on the emulator when I use [Ctrl+Clicks] to detect multi-touch for two fingers, I receive an event ACTION_POINTER_DOWN indicating that the second finger was down on the screen.

[image]

But on Android Emulator using API 30, I never receive the ACTION_POINTER_DOWN event and the multi-touch does not work. When I change the API version to lower version < 30, for the same emulated device it starts working. So the problem only occurs for devices that use API30 (I don't have an actual device that runs Android API30, so I am not sure if this only happens on the emulator or not). Is it somehow disabled by default from the developer options or the settings?

Comment: I have tested it on actual device that uses Android API 30, and it works! But the problem remains for the emulator.